# -(BOOL)insertSettings:(Settings *&)pObjSettingsRefPtr; is causing declaration error

Tags: iphone, method-parameters

```
-(BOOL)insertSettings:(Settings *&)pObjSettingsRefPtr;
```

Is causing declaration error,i am getting error as `expecting ")"` at the `Settings*&` param in the method declaration and `definition.parameter` is  `Settings *&`

But it is not taking `* and &` as well unfortuately in question editing i found stackoverflow is also not showing `(Settings *&)` it is not showing `*`

Comment: Try using this -(BOOL)insertSettings:(Settings *)pObjSettingsRefPtr;

Comment: do you understand question?i need reference as pointer

Comment: Need reference Pointer then use -(BOOL)insertSettings:(Settings **)pObjSettingsRefPtr; and use pObjSettingsRefPtr as *pObjSettingsRefPtr in this function

Comment: Is your source file Objective-C++ (i.e. is it named `.mm`)? Object references are a C++ feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use reference pointer then pass argument like this

```
-(BOOL)insertSettings:(Settings **)pObjSettingsRefPtr;
```

and then use `pObjSettingsRefPtr` as `*pObjSettingsRefPtr` everywhere in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` declaration specifier for byref argument passing is C++ only, and won't work in Objective-C. Use

```
- (BOOL)insertSettings:(Settings **)settings
```

etc. instead.

Comment: thanks i got the solution how to close this question otherwise it is causing problem as nobody is watching